# unable to create service caused by exception

Tags: android, exception, runtime-error

hi i am developing an application using a third party libraries.I am getting unable to create service and the log cat shows it is caused by client exception and the sdk guide says it as: This class throws the exceptions specific to errors that occur within the SDK.So is there a way to handle the errors within sdk.Please let me know your ideas
logcat:

```
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.xyz.android.ui.service.security.UserLoginService: com.xyz.android.core.exception.xyz ClientException
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2697)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:159)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268): Caused by: com.xyz.android.core.exception.xyzClientException
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at com.xyz.android.config.XyzApplicationConfig.getHostContext(XyzApplicationConfig.java:160)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at com.xyz.android.core.service.SecurityManagerService.<init>(SecurityManagerService.java:117)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at com.xyz.android.ui.service.security.UserLoginService.onCreate(UserLoginService.java:100)
10-03 16:59:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(14268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2687)
```

Comment: Have you declared you service in the manifest ?

Comment: Show us the logcat. Why don't people understand that it's almost impossible to guess what is causing the problem without some code or some stack trace?

Comment: yes i declared service in manifest and also while I am debugging error pops up when the bind service is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the technical support for whatever library is providing you with `com.xyz.android.ui.service.security.UserLoginService`, and ask them what a `com.xyz.android.core.exception.xyzClientException` is.